# How to pass a JS array to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I have been working on a code for image tagging. What I have achieved is, the user can tag an image by drawing a box over the image and save them. the tag details are stored in the database.

I have two files :
game2.php
gallery.php

The game2.php is the file where the user makes the tag over the image and store the data in the table. Also, I created an array to store the image and the tag details. till this, it works fine.

In the gallery.php , the images that are tag must be displayed, for that, I was thinking of using the array that holds the image name and tag details. the image for the expected output is in image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOxge.png).

**Game2.JS:**

```
  var imgarray=[];

    $('.btn_success').click(function(){

        var areas = $('img#img01').selectAreas('areas');
        displayAreas(areas);

        var x_value= document.getElementById('x').value;
        var y_value= document.getElementById('y').value;
        var w_value= document.getElementById('w').value;
        var h_value= document.getElementById('h').value;
        var fullPath = document.getElementById("img01").src;
        var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
 

        document.getElementById("result").value = filename;

        var img_name= document.getElementById('result').value;
       

        imgarray.push({"img_name":img_name,"x":x_value,"y":y_value,"w":w_value,"h":h_value});
       
      });
```

in the above code, I used imgarray to store the imagename and tag details. and I tried using ajax to send this array to PHP.

```
$("#Proceed").click(function(){
    return imgarray;

    $.ajax({
     url: "gallery.php",
     method: "POST",
     data: { imgarray : imgarray },
     dataType: "json"
    });

   });
```

**Gallery.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $imgarray = $_POST['imgarray'];

?>

<div id="gallery">
<?php
  foreach ($imgarray as $i) {

 ?>
  <img src="<?php echo "$i"; ?>" >

 <?php }
  ?>

</div>
```

**Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf06k.png):** tag page where the user clicks confirm to store the tag details and image name in the area
[image]

**Image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOxge.png):**: Expected output

[image]

In the gallery.php, I tried to get the array from game2.php and display them on the page. But something is not right in my approach, because it gives an error on gallery.php like "undefined index for $imgarray". Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Check your HTML file - are you making a proper `POST` request? If not, that `$_POST` variable will be empty. I'm also assuming `Game2.php` is a typo - that's a JS file. not PHP

Comment: @serraosays thats where i m confused , idk if im making a proper post request. Can you help me out

Comment: The first line in your `$("#Proceed").click(function(){` is `return imgarray;`, which means the AJAX call below it will never happen.

Comment: @Joskaa - your code is kind of a mess. It would be good to go through, clean it up and comment about what you're doing. Post the HTML as well if you can, that's where you'd make the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

you would use JSON.stringify(obj) to pass the obj as string. and use json_decode($objString) to decode to an obj.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url('admin/js2php_proc'); ?>" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="str" name="str" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>   
<script>
    var jsarray = new Array();
    jsarray[0] = "Saab";
    jsarray[1] = "Volvo";
    jsarray[2] = "BMW";      

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click( function() {
            $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
                 $('#str').val(JSON.stringify(jsarray)),  
                 //$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
                 function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
            });
        });
        $("#myForm").submit( function() {
            return false;   
        });
    });
</script>

//Capture data array from AJAX and process it...
    function js2php_proc() {
        $str = json_decode($_POST['str'], true); 
        echo json_encode($str);
    }
```